# Rails: CropperJS displaying broken image link to an image link from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform

I am having issues with viewing an uploaded image from my google cloud bucket. It displays a broken image link instead rather than the actual intended image. This is within an .erb file as I am using Ruby on Rails.

I am intending for it to be able to edit the crop of the image.

*edit.html.erb*

```
<div class="container page">
    <h1 class="text-center">Crop Image Online</h1>
    <div class="form-group container">
      <label for="file">Upload Image File:</label>
      <input class="form-control box" accept="image/*" type="file" required id="file-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <div class="result">
      <%# This is original crop %>
      <%= image_tag @image.crop_image_url, class: "skeleton"  %>
      <%# This is full image %>
      <%= image_tag "https://storage.googleapis.com/myprojbucket202212345/parent_images/#{@image.parent_id}", class: "skeleton poster"  %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--rightbox-->
    <div class="box-2 img-result hide">
      <!-- result of crop -->
      <img class="cropped" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <!-- input file -->
    <div class="box">
      <%# <div class="options hide"> %>
      <div class="options">
        <label> Width</label>
        <input type="number" class="img-w" value="300" min="100" max="1200" />
      </div>
      <!-- save btn -->
      <%# <button class="btn save hide">Save</button> %>
      <button class="btn save ">Save</button>

      <!-- download btn -->
      <a href="" class="btn download hide">Download</a>
    </div>
    <%= link_to "Return to Review", images_review_path, class:"active-btn", style: "text-decoration: none;" %>

  </div>
```

It may be an issue related to the google link generated, as it works with normal urls. How do I fix this?

Comment: When you copy the link to the image in the navbar, does it show the image ? To me it is a CORS issue. Have you checked CORS bucket configuration at Google ?

Comment: I have fixed it by updating my CORS permissions on my google bucket. Thank you!